# MYSQL: two joins on same table become double grouped count. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this simplified structure:

```
customers
-----------------------
id
name
salesagents_id      (each client has their own sales agent assigned)

salesagents
-----------------------
id
name


visits
-----------------------
customers_id
salesagents_id
date
```

I need to get a list of all the clients, plus three additional fields:

1. Name of sales agent assigned to client
2. Number of visits received by salesagents
3. Number of visits received in last month

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT clients.*, salesagents.name, COUNT(v1.id) as visits_number, COUNT(v2.id) as visits_number_last_month
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `salesagents` ON `clients`.`salesagents_id`=`salesagents`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `visits` as `v1` ON `clients`.`id` = `v1`.`clients_id`
LEFT JOIN `visits` as `v2` ON `clients`.`id` = `v2`.`clients_id` AND `v2`.`date` > FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
GROUP BY `clients`.`id`
```

The problem is that the two joins on the same table makes up double number of visits.

What else could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct Count may solve your problem

```
SELECT clients.*, salesagents.name, COUNT(DISTINCT v1.id) as visits_number, COUNT( DISTINCT v2.id) as visits_number_last_month
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `salesagents` ON `clients`.`salesagents_id`=`salesagents`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `visits` as `v1` ON `clients`.`id` = `v1`.`clients_id`
LEFT JOIN `visits` as `v2` ON `clients`.`id` = `v2`.`clients_id` AND `v2`.`date` > FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
GROUP BY `clients`.`id`
```

Comment: Great!! So simple, and this solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SUM` and `CASE WHEN`. The first `COUNT` counts all visitors, the second expression only counts the visitors if the date condition matches. Therefore you use the `CASE WHEN` expression with adds 1 if the condition fits:

```
SELECT 
      clients.*
    , salesagents.name, COUNT(v1.id) as visits_number
    , SUM(
          CASE WHEN `v1`.`date` > FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))) 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
      END) as visits_number_last_month
FROM `clients`
LEFT JOIN `salesagents` ON `clients`.`salesagents_id`=`salesagents`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `visits` as `v1` ON `clients`.`id` = `v1`.`clients_id`
GROUP BY `clients`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c1.*, s1.name, v1.visits1, v2.visits2
from clients c1
left join salesagents s1
  on c1.salesagents_id = s1.id
left join
    (select clients_id, count(distinct id) as visits1
    from visits
    group by clients_id) v1
  on v1.clients_id = c1.id
left join
    (select vx.clients_id, count(distinct vx.id) as visits2
    from visits vx
    where vx.date >FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
    group by vx.clients_id) v2
  on v2.clients_id = c1.id
```

Comment: Any explanations to this?

Comment: @rbr94 This completes the aggregation in each subquery (with the distinct). It's not the most efficient, but will prevent issues with grouping